# Rails inherited resources usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using [Inherited Resources](http://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) for my Rails 2.3 web service app. 
It's a great library which is part of Rails 3.

I'm trying to figure out the best practice for outputting the result.

```
class Api::ItemsController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :xml, :json
  def create
    @error = nil 
    @error = not_authorized if !@user
    @error = not_enough_data("item") if params[:item].nil? 

    @item = Item.new(params[:item])
    @item.user_id = @user.id
    if !@item.save
      @error = validation_error(@item.errors)
    end 
    if !@error.nil?
      respond_with(@error)
    else 
      respond_with(@swarm)
    end 
  end

end
```

It works well when the request is successful. However, when there's any error, I get a "Template is missing" error. @error is basically a hash of message and status, e.g. `{:message => "Not authorized", :status => 401}`. It seems `respond_with` only calls `to_xml` or `to_json` with the particular model the controller is associated with.

What is an elegant way to handle this? 
I want to avoid creating a template file for each action and each format (create.xml.erb and create.json.erb in this case)

Basically I want:

```
/create.json [POST] => {"name": "my name", "id":1}  # when successful 
/create.json [POST] => {"message" => "Not authorized", "status" => 401} # when not authorized
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things before we start:

- First off. This is Ruby. You know there's an `unless` command. You can stop doing `if !`
- Also, you don't have to do the double negative of `if !*.nil?` – Do `if *.present?`
- You do not need to initiate a variable by making it `nil`. Unless you are setting it in a `before_chain`, which you would just be overwriting it in future calls anyway.

What you will want to do is use the `render :json` method. Check the API but it looks something like this:

```
render :json => { :success => true, :user => @user.to_json(:only => [:name]) }
```

Answer (score 0):

authorization should be implemented as callback (before_filter), and rest of code should be removed and used as inherited. Only output should be parametrized.Too many custom code here...